# Default argument alternative to None?

Tags: python, function, default-parameters

I am writing a function a little like this:

```
def parse(string, default=None):
    try:
        ...  # Body of function here
    except ParseError:
        if default is not None:
            return default
        raise
```

But then I run into problems if I actually want the function to return `None`.

```
if len(sys.argv) > 4:
    if flag.ignore_invalid:
        result = parse(sys.argv[4], None)  # Still raises error
    else:
        result = parse(sys.argv[4])
```

What I have tried to fix this is:

```
_DEFAULT = object()

def parse(string, default=_DEFAULT):
    ...
        if default is not _DEFAULT:
            ...
```

But this seems like I'm overthinking it, and it seems like there's an easier way to do it.

The `any` and `all` functions do this (Allowing `None` as a default), but I don't know how.

Comment: `object` is a reasonable sentinel if `None` isn't appropriate - note that you can use `default=object` (i.e. the class) rather than `default=_DEFAULT` (an instance) to save the extra assignment. `object is object`, too, which avoids issues with return values with odd `__eq__` implementations. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1118454/3001761

Comment: Your `_DEFAULT` is a perfectly reasonable way to go.

Comment: The default value just needs to be a value which can *never* be a valid argument passed by a caller. A custom instance works well because the caller while the caller could in theory create an object that is *equal* to your sentinel, he can never create one that `is` your sentinel. And if he explicitly calls the method with a reference to your sentinel, well, that's hardly your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're frequently needing to ignore the `ParseError`, I would just let `parse` throw all of the time, and only catch it in the places I need to:

```
try:
    parse(sys.argv[4])
except ParseError:
    if not flag.ignore_invalid:
        raise
```

Though if you must have a default value, then the `_DEFAULT` solution is OK.

Comment: I think refactoring my whole code was the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

How about using keyword parameters, then you can check whether the user passed anything at all:

```
def parse(string, **kw):
    try:
        ...  # Body of function here
    except ParseError:
        if 'default' in kw:
            return kw['default']
        raise
```

the downside is that you won't catch if anyone misspells `default`.